# How to create responive scale user interface out of a background image with text box

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I have an image of a user interface, including textboxes. I want to show a text inside this textbox image. How to make it stay within the textbox and scale accordingly on window resize?

Code:

```
var resize = function(n) {
  const area = document.getElementById('area');

  const width = window.outerWidth * .3 + 'px';
  const height = window.outerHeight * .3 + 'px';

  area.style.height = height;
  area.style.width = width;
  area.style.backgroundSize = [width, height].join(' ');
};


window['onresize'] = resize;
resize();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/eguneys/CGmCe/13084/

Comment: Why is the requirement to use an image of a user interface?  Why not code out the html/css to look like the image?

Comment: I am making a game clone and using it's images.

Comment: Go the extra yard and code the interfaces yourself using HTML/CSS.  You will go nuts trying to get responsive to work with an input over an image.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the background as an actual img element inside a container div, then add CSS to absolutely position and size the text over the img relative to the container div. For instance:

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}

#some_text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/HqCkexI.png?1" />
    <div id="some_text">Some text</div>
</div>
```